# How to Create\Remove destination using JMS API

Tags: java, jms

I want to create and remove destinations in my JMS provider programmatically using JMS APIs only (without provider-specific APIs).
Is there a way to do it?
I couldn't find relevant APIs in javax.jms APIs, and all the online solutions I could find are provider specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only thing you can create are temporary queues/topics.  There is no ability in the JMS API to create a permanent queue/topic.